# golang shortcut syntax for slice literal of pointers to structs

Tags: pointers, go, literals

Given

```
type foo struct {
    id int
}
```

the two look equivalent

```
var foos = []*foo{
    {1},
    {2},
    {3}}

var foos = []*foo{
    &foo{1},
    &foo{2},
    &foo{3}}
```

Why is that? Can't find mentioning of it in TGPL though.

https://play.golang.org/p/JXxZaybbWnV

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can skip the type in [composite literals](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Composite_literals).

> Within a composite literal of array, slice, or map type T, elements or map keys that are themselves composite literals may elide the respective literal type if it is identical to the element or key type of T. Similarly, elements or keys that are addresses of composite literals may elide the &T when the element or key type is *T.